# EtherscanProvider.getHistory(), got an error;

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ethers.js

```
nodejs.SERVER_ERRORError: missing response (requestBody=null, requestMethod="GET", serverError={"code":"ECONNRESET","path":null,"host":"api.etherscan.io","port":443}, url="https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x99b02491Fd1A9a7A97a31d046767c08D5cCc9A1d&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=9D13ZE7XSBTJ94N9BNJ2MA33VMAY2YPIRB", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.4.0)
at Logger.makeError (D:\workspace\defi\pms-defi\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:199:21)
at Logger.throwError (D:\workspace\defi\pms-defi\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:208:20)
at D:\workspace\defi\pms-defi\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:213:36
at step (D:\workspace\defi\pms-defi\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
at Object.throw (D:\workspace\defi\pms-defi\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
at rejected (D:\workspace\defi\pms-defi\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:6:65)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

reason: "missing response"
code: "SERVER_ERROR"
requestBody: null
requestMethod: "GET"
serverError: {"code":"ECONNRESET","path":null,"host":"api.etherscan.io","port":443}
url: "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x99b02491Fd1A9a7A97a31d046767c08D5cCc9A1d&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=9D13ZE7XSBTJ94N9BNJ2MA33VMAY2YPIRB"
name: "SERVER_ERRORError"
pid: 27988
hostname: ...
```

Here's my code:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const provider = new ethers.providers.EtherscanProvider();
const address = "0x99b02491Fd1A9a7A97a31d046767c08D5cCc9A1d";
const history = await provider.getHistory(address);
```

Where do I have problems writing this way, can you help me see it?

ethers version : "ethers": "^5.4.7"

Answer (score 0):

In your error, `ECONNRESET` is visible. It means that the connection was unexpectedly closed by the server. This can be possible due to some network issues between you and the Etherscan server or problems with the Etherscan server itself (which is less likely and immediately to get fixed). Can you ensure your internet connection is up and try again?